# Send initial message from power virtual agent

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-virtual-agents

I am trying to send initial message from power virtual agents, but i don't have any idea how can i do this. I just want after install app when bot load it will send a message to team channel

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirement and share the steps you are following?

Comment: I create a bot from power virtual agent and i add it with my app i just want to send a  message from adaptive card. When a user install my app

Comment: Please follow this documentation(https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/make-your-power-virtual-agents-bot-start-the-conversation-using-a-custom-canvas/) which explains how to send proactive message via Power virtual agent. Also refer:https://dhina.org/2020/03/30/building-proactive-bot-with-power-virtual-agents/

Comment: After install app from ms team i want to send greeting message in ms team channel

Comment: Please refer this: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Bot-Administration/Bot-greeting-first/m-p/803101#M91

Answer (score 0):

To make your bot start the conversation, you’ll need to deploy a custom canvas that includes arguments that cause the default system greeting topic to be displayed when the bot loads. Please follow this documentation(https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/make-your-power-virtual-agents-bot-start-the-conversation-using-a-custom-canvas/) which explains how to send proactive message via Power virtual agent.

You can also refer this: https://dhina.org/2020/03/30/building-proactive-bot-with-power-virtual-agents/